# Can you modify http request headers in a Safari extension?

Tags: http-headers, safari-extension

I can do this in FF and IE, and I know it doesn't exist in Chrome yet.  Anybody know if you can do this in a Safari plugin?  I can't find anything that says one way or another in the documentation.

Comment: I looked into it, and figure it is not possible on Chrome/Safari/Opera

Comment: It now exists in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome has the chrome.webRequest http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html

Answer (score 9):

You can now do this in Safari, without any extensions, using [Local Overrides](https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/#configuring-local-overrides).

1. Either from the Sources or Network tab, control/right click on the resource you wish to override.
2. Select **Create Request Local Override**.
3. Under **Local Overrides** in the left panel of the Web Inspector, control/right click on the resource override.
4. Select **Edit Local Override...**.
5. Click **Add Header** (or, change the value of an existing header).
6. Enter the header name and value.
7. If this was for a POST, PUT, etc. request, click **Include original request data** (otherwise, you will also override the request body, instead of just the headers).
8. Try your request again. The overridden headers should apply. You can verify this by inspecting the request in the Network tab.

Comment: Can this be used via extensions?

Comment: This only works if developer tools are open for the site in question.

Comment: I tried to used this feature for all requests towards a specific domain. However, I couldn't succeed. Local overrides weren't applied to XHR requests under the same domain.

Answer (score 6):

Safari has added extension support but its APIs don't let you have granular level control over Request & Response as compared to Chrome/Firefox/Edge.

To have granular level control over your Request and Response, you need setup a system wide proxy instead.
[Requestly](https://requestly.io/for-safari/) Desktop App automatically does this for you and on top of that, you can do various types of modifications too like:

- Modify Request/Response Headers
- Redirect URLs
- Modify Response
- Delay Network request
- Insert Custom Scripts
- Change User-Agent

Here's an article about header modification using requestly
https://requestly.io/feature/modify-request-response-headers/

Disclaimer: I work at Requestly

Answer (score 3):

**Edit (November 2021):** as pointed out in the comments, ParosProxy seems to no longer exist (and was last released ~2006 from what I can see). There are more modern options for debugging on Mac (outside of browser plugins on non-Safari browsers) like [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/). Rather than adding another list of links that might expire, I'll instead advise people to search for "debugging proxy" on their platform of choice instead.

**Original Answer (2012):**

The Safari "Develop" menu in advanced preferences allows you to partially customize headers (like the user agent), but it is quite limited.

However, if a particular browser or app does not allow you to alter the headers, just take it out of the equation.  You can use things like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [ParosProxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/) (and many others) to alter the requests regardless of the application sending the request.

They also have the advantage of allowing you to make sure that you are sending the same headers regardless of the application in question and (depending on your requirements) potentially work across multiple browsers and apps without modification.

Comment: What if we are testing a web application and we have to add one or more extra headers to all our web requests ? Is using a proxy to do this as easy as using a browser plugin ? I wonder if we have to manually modify each web request or if there is a way to automate it inside the proxy.

Comment: @testerjoe2 at the time this was asked, Safari was a supported browser on Windows, it was discontinued later in 2012

Comment: @AdamComerford The ParosProxy-link is a dead-end nowadays :(

Comment: @JonasHeinisch yes indeed - a lot changes in almost a decade. I've added an edit at the top of the answer but left the original for reference