# How to modify HTTP(s) response headers using Safari extension?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, http-headers

We can currently modify the HTTP(s) response headers in Chrome. How can we modify HTTP(s) response header using Safari extension?

Comment: Hi @Sambuddha Basu.. did you ever got its solution? I am facing the same issue.. to modify headers using safari extension.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/70751551/6130579

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you modify http request headers in a Safari extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350743/can-you-modify-http-request-headers-in-a-safari-extension)